# Си, вывод чисел наоборот

Tags: c

Пишу программу для перевода из десятичной системы счисления в любую другую, пока без перевода чисел в буквы.

Вопрос: Как мне вывести мой остаток от деления наоборот? Сейчас он выводится так:

```
    int main()
    {
        unsigned int n, k;
        printf("n = ");
        scanf("%i", &n);
        printf("k = ");
        scanf("%i", &k);

        if (n < k)
        {
            printf("%i", n);
        }
        else{
            while (n > 0)
            {
                printf("%i ", n % k);
                n = (int)n / k;
            }
        }

    }
```

Например при 10 в двоичной системе вывод будет: 0 1 0 1, а мне нужен наоборот 1 0 1 0.

Какой самый оптимальный способ добиться этого? Мне пришла идея создать статический массив чисел и записывать в него результат, а потом выводить. Но ведь его размера может и не хватить, при очень длинном числе.

Comment: Длиннее 32 символов у вас число не получится, заводите массив.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за обратную связь. А почему больше 32 символов ничего не получится?

Comment: Потому что вы используете unsigned int. Обычно этот тип имеет размер 32 бита. Самое длинное число у вас будет при переводе в двоичную систему. Формально говоря, вам надо завести массив размером sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT + 1. +1 чтобы '\0'  в конце добавить.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, проблема в том, что мне нужны строки для хранения каждого из чисел. Так как некоторые могут быть с буквами, помимо "неизвестного размера массива" мне нужно ещё как-то подобрать размер для каждой строки в этом массиве :(

Comment: Может можно как-то вовсе избежать массивов и просто сделать вывод наоборот?

Comment: И буквы, и цифры занимают 1 байт в массиве char.

Comment: Вывод наоборот можно сделать достаточно легко, если использовать рекурсию. Но так вы точно не сэкономите память.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n, k;
    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    printf("k = ");
    scanf("%i", &k);

    if (n < k)
    {
        printf("%i", n);
    }
    else{
        // Создаём массив под 33 элемента, заполненный нулями
        char buf[sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT + 1] = {0};
        // Получаем указатель на предпоследний элемент массива
        // В последнем элементе должен быть 0, чтобы была правильная строка
        char *p = &buf[sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT - 1];
        while (n > 0)
        {
            // Записываем в ячейку, на которую указывает p, символ
            // Добавляем '0', чтобы получился символ соответствующей цифры
            // Когда будете писать для сс с цифрами в виде букв,
            // нужно будет получать символ как-то иначе
            *p = n % k + '0';
            // Сдвигаем указатель на одну ячейку влево
            p--;
            n = (int)n / k;
        }
        // Выводим строку, начиная с первой цифры числа
        printf("%s\n", p + 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: А можете подробнее рассказать, что в этом коде происходит с момента "char buf"?

Comment: Добавил комментариев